# Possible to designate a blazor component's parameter as a route so it's resolved in the same way href is in anchors?

Tags: .net, blazor

This is for .NET 8 and the most current iteration of Blazor in Visual Studio 2022.

When you type the name of a page/component into an anchor's href, intellisense gives suggestions and the string gets resolved to a route. I'd like to be able to declare a parameter in my own component so that it's treated the same way.

So to be clear, I'm looking for a data type or attribute to apply here:

```
@code {
    [Parameter] public string Href{ get; set; } = "";
}
```

Normally I'd just navigate to definition, but in this case I'd have to dig into the interpreter to see what's going on which seems a little less straightforward.

Comment: You are missing some information from your question. What IDE are you talking about? Can you post an example of a route that works and one that doesn't? Can you show these in use in an href?

Comment: Updated. Note that the question is about how intellisense treats a parameter, and not any specific route.